# how to optimize delete queries from (for) multiple tables (into one)?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-delete

ok i am currently deleting successfully from multiple tables with three queries selecting the row where category_id is present, except one, there i use a subquery to get the post_id by category_id. How can do it in a more efficient and comprehensive manner ? Thanks !

```
/**
 * delete category by id
 * @param $id
 * @return bool
 */
public function delete_category($id){

    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE categories.id = $id");
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM comments
                      WHERE comments.post_id = ANY (SELECT post_id
                                                    FROM posts
                                                    WHERE category_id = $id)");
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM posts
                      WHERE posts.category_id = $id
                      AND posts.category_id IS NOT NULL");
}
```

The code works fine it gives desired results, but it seems kind of gross, how can i optimize it ?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the foreign keys?

Comment: yes i thought about that in this case too but i don't use foreign keys yet here, still shaky in that regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a [multi-table DELETE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#idm140563991415552).

You essentially take a SELECT query that selects the rows that you want to delete and you change the `SELECT * FROM` to `DELETE <table_name>, <table_name> FROM`, with `<table_name>, <table_name>` being the tables to delete from.

For example if you have these DELETE queries:

```
DELETE FROM comments WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE category_id = 1);
DELETE FROM posts WHERE category_id = 1;
DELETE FROM categories WHERE category_id = 1;
```

You can rewrite them as a SELECT that selects all rows you want deleted:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
JOIN posts USING (category_id)
JOIN comments USING (post_id)
WHERE category_id = 1
```

Then you can replace the `SELECT` with the multi-table `DELETE`:

```
DELETE categories, posts, comments
FROM categories
JOIN posts USING (category_id)
JOIN comments USING (post_id)
WHERE category_id = 1
```